# Filament 3 - Return custom search results with multiple option labels

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-10, laravel-filament

How can I achieve that, in the case of a search, I receive not just a single option label as the "option label" but can also display multiple option labels?
In the case of a product search, I would like to display not only the product name but also its item number.

```
Forms\Components\Select::make('product_id')->label('Product')
    ->searchable()
    ->getSearchResultsUsing(function (string $search) {
        $product = self::ProductSearch($search);
        return $product;
    })
    ->getOptionLabelUsing(function ($value) {
        $product = self::ProductSearch($value);
        return $product;
}),

public static function ProductSearch($queryValue)
{
    $product = Product::leftjoin('option_table_one', 'products.id', '=', 'option_table_one.product_id')
    ->select(
        'products.*',
        'option_table_one.item_number',
        'option_table_one.price',
    )
    ->where('option_table_one.item_number', 'like', '%' . $queryValue . '%')
    ->pluck('name', 'id')
    ->toArray();

    return $product;
}
```

The code above returns:

```
<select>
<option value="1">Product Name</option>
<option value="2">Product Name</option>
<option value="3">Product Name</option>
</select>
```

This is how i want to display it:

```
<select>
<option value="1">Item Number - Product Name - Price</option>
<option value="2">Item Number - Product Name - Price </option>
<option value="3">Item Number - Product Name - Price </option>
</select>
```